# jaxb hide child element when parent element is xsi:nil=true

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have below xml, when offer element has xsi:nil="true" then i dont want to show childrean elements even that child element xsi:nil=true,

In the beloe xml i have four offer elements, i want to show child elements(endDate) only for the first two Offer elements. How can i do that in jaxb?

```
   <snapshots xmlns="http://ws.sample.com/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" query="after=2014-06-25" type="web">
<current>2014-07-02</current>
<Offers>
    <Offer xsi:type="OfferWEB" Id="1">
        <endDate>2014-09-25</endDate>
    </Offer>
    <Offer xsi:type="OfferWEB" Id="5">
        <endDate xsi:nil="true"/>
    </Offer>
    <Offer xsi:type="OfferWEB" Id="2" xsi:nil="true">
        <endDate xsi:nil="true"/>
    </Offer>
    <Offer xsi:type="OfferWEB" Id="3" xsi:nil="true">
        <endDate xsi:nil="true"/>
    </Offer>
</Offers>
```

Comment: How do you marshal objects to xml?

Comment: Is `OfferWEB` a `JAXBElement`?

Comment: Yes OfferWeb is a JAXBElement.

Comment: endate has annotation @xmlelement(nillable=true)